# Sorting Footable rows by Date Column (gg/mm/aaaa)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, footable, columnsorting

I'm using [footable library](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/) for showing table. Each row has a Date column, I would like to sort this table by the Date column (on column header click).

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-type="date-eu">Data Scadenza</th>
    <th>Titolo</th>
    <th>Inviato da</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="promemoria in elencoPromemoria">
    <td>{{promemoria.DataScadenza | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
    <td>{{promemoria.Titolo}}</td>
    <td>{{promemoria.InviatoDa}}</td>
    <td><a ng-show="promemoria.Link" ng-attr-ui-sref="{{promemoria.Link || false}}"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The variable `promemoria.DataScadenza` contains a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` so:

- If I use `{{promemoria.DataScadenza | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}` I can see the date in the right euro-zone (dd/mm/yyyy) style but I can't sort correctly.
- If I use `{{promemoria.DataScadenza}}` I can sort correctly but I see the dates in the USA-zone (yyyy-mm-dd) style.

PS: The other two columns (Titolo,InviatoDa) are sorted alphabetically and working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data-format-string` attribute in the table header to define custom format for data.

Below is redefined version of your code

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-type="date" data-format-string="dd/MM/yyyy">Data Scadenza</th>
    <th>Titolo</th>
    <th>Inviato da</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="promemoria in elencoPromemoria">
    <td>{{promemoria.DataScadenza | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
    <td>{{promemoria.Titolo}}</td>
    <td>{{promemoria.InviatoDa}}</td>
    <td><a ng-show="promemoria.Link" ng-attr-ui-sref="{{promemoria.Link || false}}"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: it didn't worked, but it was just a matter of timezone, i just included the local.js library and it worked fine :D